# FreeNAS, OS X Yosemite and automount

Tags: macos, performance, nfs, freenas

I've got FreeNAS 9.3 server (HP Microserver N54L) and connecting to it via NFS from my multiple OS X systems (running OS X Yosemite 10.10.1). I've always had low performance over the network (1Gig ethernet) and have roughly 40 megabytes per second transfer rate, while locally on file server, write speed is about 140-150Mb/s.

via NFS:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test  bs=64k count=16k
16384+0 records in
16384+0 records out
1073741824 bytes transferred in 27.447623 secs (39119665 bytes/sec)
```

locally on FreeNAS:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test_local  bs=64k count=16k
16384+0 records in
16384+0 records out
1073741824 bytes transferred in 7.575698 secs (141735033 bytes/sec)
```

Wondering what options should I use for mounting NFS shares to increase performance? Only thing I came up with it to change protocol to TCP, which will increase rsize and wsize to 32768.

Using `async` option is discouraged by man page - Use of the async option may improve performance, but only at the risk of losing data if the server crashes because the client will not be making sure that all data is committed to stable storage on the server.

So question is: anyone figured out how to increase performance?

Thank you.

Comment: did you check the NAS-ethernet cables, the switch, made some crosschecks (like mac2mac)?

Comment: NFS is used more often in Unix circles, so you might have good results researching Unix and Linux NFS tuning.  For example, here's on from Linux.  http://www.slashroot.in/how-do-linux-nfs-performance-tuning-and-optimization  Finding something on BSD to BSD NFS performance would likely be perfect, since FreeNAS and OS X are based on BSD.